# Filter an array based on an object property

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, something as follows:

```
var events = [
  { date: "18-02-2016", name: "event A" },
  { date: "22-02-2016", name: "event B" },
  { date: "19-02-2016", name: "event C" },
  { date: "22-02-2016", name: "event D" }
];
```

And I have a date, for example "22-02-2016". How can I get an array with all object which date is the same as the given date? So in this example I would get events B and D.

Comment: Search for `array filter`

Comment: Or this one: [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2722159/218196) ... please use the search before asking a new question.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could use array's [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function:

```
function filter_dates(event) {
    return event.date == "22-02-2016";
}

var filtered = events.filter(filter_dates);
```

The `filter_dates()` method can be standalone as in this example to be reused, or it could be inlined as an anonymous method - totally your choice =]

A quick / easy alternative is just a straightforward loop:

```
var filtered = [];
for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    if (events[i].date == "22-02-2016") {
        filtered.push(events[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to return all results that contain "2016", how should the function change?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir For that case, the `event.date == "..."` conditional would need to change to `event.date.includes('2016')` (alternatively, you could also use `.indexOf('2016')`)

Answer (score 20):

User [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as follows:.

```
var filteredEvents = events.filter(function(event){
    return event.date == '22-02-2016';
});
```