# Remove object from array of objects based on object key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object like

```
let arr = [
    {isManaged: true, id:1},
    {isManaged: false, id:2},
    {isManaged:false, id:3}
]
```

to get the values which are true, i do

```
arr.map(shift => ({
    id: shift.id,
    isPartnerManaged: shift.isManaged,
}))
```

but this will only return me the values where i true, now, I want to remove them from the array of objects. I tried to use the `array.pop` but i don't know what index to feed it. Any ideeas?

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter an array based on an object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231008/filter-an-array-based-on-an-object-property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arr = arr.filter(shift => shift.isManaged);`

Answer (score -1):

You could filter the array and build new objects.

```js
var array = [{ isManaged: true, id: 1 }, { isManaged: false, id: 2 }, { isManaged: false, id: 3 }],
    result = array
        .filter(({ isManaged }) => isManaged)
        .map(({ isManaged: isPartnerManaged, id }) => ({ id, isPartnerManaged }));

console.log(result);
```